# Sort datatable rows by date

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I read from database some data to datatable, In the database I have column that looks like:

```
+---------------------+
|  DATE (TEXT)        |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-10 12:39:22 |
+---------------------+
| 2018-12-10 15:39:22 |
+---------------------+
 .
 .
 .
```

I want to sort the **datatable** rows by their date, what's the best way to applay that? my code lookes like:

```
 public MyPage()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myDataTable= new DataTable();
        this.myDataTable= Query("SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM myTable"); 
        SortByDate();          
  }
```

I strated from converting the text to datetime like:

```
void SortByDate()
{
        //convert date column from text to Date
        foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
            row["Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DATE"]);                        
 }
```

but how to sort the rows now?

Comment: I don't get it why don't you use `ORDER BY DATE ASC/DESC` within your sql query.

Comment: @Valkyrie good idea

Comment: If you want to sort the datatable itself, you can do it with:
`this.myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "DATE ASC";
this.myDataTable = this.myDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();`